# Sunspot: Sort/order facet results by attribute e.g. created_at

Tags: ruby, sorting, facet, sunspot

Asset model:

```
searchable do
   text :title
   text :description
   time :created_at
   integer :category_ids, :multiple => true, :references => Category
end
```

Controller:

```
search = Asset.search() do
   keywords(h(params[:query]), :fields => [:title, :description])
   facet(:category_ids)
   order_by :created_at
end
```

I would not like to sort my facet `:Category_ides` via `:count` (number of hits). The categories should be ordered by `created_at`. Looking at the documentation `facet(:category_ids, :sort` => `:count || :index`), both options won't work for me.

How can I solve this order problem for facets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just load the facets and then sort them yourself:

```
result = Product.solr_search do |s|
  s.keywords params[:q]
  s.facet :category_id
  s.paginate :per_page => 3, :page => @page
end

facet_rows = result.facet(:category_id).rows.sort { |left,right| left.instance.created_at <=> right.instance.created_at }
```